# Cannot make first ACL example

Tags: zend-framework, acl

I want to load My ACL plugin to the application, and just start working with ACL

I follow this [tutorial](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/02/06/zend_acl-part-1-misconceptions-and-simple-acls/)  to start learning ACL.

I make like this

```
 class My_ACL extends Zend_Acl {

public function __construct() {


    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('member'));
    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));

    //discussions is a module name
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('discussions'));

    //privileges is a module name
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('privileges'));

     //default is a the default mdule
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('default'));


    //allow admin every thing
    $this->allow('admin');
   //tmp just for testing
      $this->allow('member');

}
```

and in the plugin I delete every thing and just keep an echo statement

```
 class Application_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

private $_acl = null;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_acl = new My_ACL();
}

public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

    $role = (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) ? 'admin' : 'member';


echo $this->_acl->isAllowed($role, $request->getModuleName() . ':' . $request->getControllerName() . ':' . $request->getActionName());

}
```

but when I try to access any url for the system this error occur

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Exception' with message 'Resource 'default:error:error' not found' in    

  D:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 312
  ( ! ) Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'default:error:error' not found in                         D:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Acl.php on line 365
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line

```
if($request->getControllerName() == 'error')  return ;
```

after

```
  $role = (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) ? 'admin' : 'member';
```

Basically whenever application error occurs ZF changes request object to module default , error controller and its error action . For that case you have not created any resource . 
By doing what I say you will be able to see 'Application Error' page which will help you fix the first problem .